# pod install is installing in different folder

Tags: ios, react-native, cocoapods

I have a pod file like:

```
platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'Project' do

  pod 'AppAuth', '>= 0.94'

  pod 'RNAWSCognito', :path => '../node_modules/amazon-cognito-identity-js'

  pod 'react-native-sqlite-storage', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-sqlite-storage'

end
```

I did `pod install` , but some of the pods are installing directly to my `Target Support File` folder within `Pods` folder.

[image: directory]

So when I try using these pods it gave error:

[image: errer] [image]

Answer (score 2):

Try this : 
`pod install --project-directory=/path/to/root/with/Podfile`